# Postgresql trigger to write data into SQL Server via ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, triggers, odbc

Is it possible to write Postgresql trigger that can write data to a SQL Server 2008 database? I have a Windows Postgresql DB (9.1) and have an existing trigger that writes data to a table called `finaldata`. Can I then have a trigger on the `finaldata` table that would write to a SQL Server via ODBC or some other connectivity option?

I am stuck with this! Should I try with plpgsql or in another language a better option?
My standard method for writing a function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."finaldata" () RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
DECLARE
BEGIN

  "Connect to SQL Server and write data to single table newdata "

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: I wouldn't go with plpgsql on this... Do you know the other PL languages? For example, PL/Python?

Comment: No sorry no Python expertise. Have you got this to work with PL/Python? Did you use the new Foreign Table feature in 9.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9.1 supports foreign tables which allow you to run selects/updates etc in Postgresql against tables that are actually in other databases.

This way a postgresql trigger (in any language) can be used.

There is a foreign data wrapper available for ODBC, which you can use to connect to SQL Server.

[Postgresql Foreign Tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigntable.html)

[ODBC Foreign Data Wrapper](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#odbc_fdw)

Comment: Looks promising - although cutting edge. Have you managed to get this to work? Is there a SQL Server wrapper or do I need the ODBC one? The link is https://github.com/ZhengYang/odbc_fdw .. but it looks pretty new

Answer (score 1):

There is [DBI-Link](http://dbi-link.projects.postgresql.org/) which you could use with plperl and an ODBC driver to access the SQL Server (untested).  Be advised though, that for proper transaction management (i. e. that the data on the SQL server always reflects the data on the PostgreSQL server) you need to implement a [two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) or something similar yourself.